# How to draw custom dynamic height curved shape in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, widget, flutter-layout

I want to draw below type of custom shape in flutter

[image]

Till now i have tried using `CustomPainter`

```
class MyBottomPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Color color;

  MyBottomPainter(this.color);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint()
      ..color = color ?? Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    var rect = Rect.fromCircle(
        center: Offset(size.width * 0.110, size.height * 0.835), radius: 40.0);

    var path = Path()
      ..moveTo(0, size.height * 0.875)
      ..addArc(rect, 0, size.width * 0.100)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(
          0, size.height * 0.875, size.width * 0.100, size.height * 0.675)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.100, size.height * 0.675,
          size.width - 40.0, size.height * 0.675)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(size.width, size.height * 0.645, size.width,
          size.height * 0.675 - 40.0)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
      ..lineTo(0, size.height);

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

I have also trying using `ShapeBorder`

```
class BottomShapeBorder extends ShapeBorder {
  const BottomShapeBorder();

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) => _getPath(rect);

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) => _getPath(rect);

  _getPath(Rect rect) {
    final r = rect.height / 2;
    final radius = Radius.circular(r);
    final offset = Rect.fromCircle(center: Offset.zero, radius: r);
    return Path()
      ..moveTo(rect.topLeft.dx, rect.topLeft.dy)
      ..relativeArcToPoint(offset.bottomLeft, clockwise: false, radius: radius)
      ..relativeArcToPoint(offset.bottomRight, clockwise: true, radius: radius)
      ..relativeArcToPoint(offset.topRight, clockwise: true, radius: radius)
      ..lineTo(rect.centerRight.dx - r, rect.centerRight.dy)
      ..relativeArcToPoint(offset.topRight, clockwise: false, radius: radius)
      ..addRect(rect);
  }

  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions {
    return EdgeInsets.all(0);
  }

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) {
    return BottomShapeBorder();
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {
  }
}
```

But I'm not getting expected output using above both the approach

can anybody help me to create this type of custom shape?

If need more information please do let me know. Thanks in advance. Your efforts will be appreciated.

Comment: you just want a `Path` or how to make that foggy effect?

Comment: @pskink i just want to make `Path` with dynamic height as per content

Comment: `@override
Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {ui.TextDirection textDirection}) {
final RADIUS = 64.0;
var r = Radius.circular(RADIUS);
var rect0 = EdgeInsets.only(top: RADIUS).deflateRect(rect);
var rrect = RRect.fromRectAndCorners(rect0, topLeft: r, bottomLeft: r, bottomRight: r);
return Path()
..moveTo(rect.topRight.dx, rect.topRight.dy)
..arcToPoint(rect.topRight + Offset(-RADIUS, RADIUS), radius: r)
..relativeLineTo(RADIUS, 0)
..addRRect(rrect);
}
`

Comment: @pskink can u please post above comment as answer how i use above code?

Comment: it is overriden `getOuterPath` method - just replace it with your version

Comment: @pskink i'm getting below output https://prnt.sc/vdyo0z

Answer (score 0):

You can use container decoration for that

```
Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color.black,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
              )),
)
```